# Puppet : Pre stage values not used in main stage

Tags: puppet

I know puppet reads all facts from a node before a run. How can I make puppet re-read the facts from a node after my pre stage module is executed and use the new facts, as a result of pre stage module execution, in main stage.

All help appreciated.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: What you are asking is multiple-catalog model in puppet. So far is not supported. Please check this discussion https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/7974.

Comment: You cannot do this with run stages.  All node facts are evaluated prior to each catalog request, then a complete catalog including resources from all declared stages is built based on those facts, and returned for the client to apply.  There are various ways to deal with that, depending on what, exactly, you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it works. The facts will only be read once, before the catalog is compiled. You can think of stages as separating your actions into groups, but they are still part of the same catalog.

You might work around this if you are allowed to restart the machine. By inserting a `reboot` resource at the end of your pre stage (make it conditional on something in the stage to avoid a reboot loop), you would skip all of the main stage when the role is run first. Once the machine reboots, the next Puppet run will be a new, clean run, and the facts will be re-read.